# Is (a/b)/c equal to a/(b*c) for integer division?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, integers, programming

Let $\div$ denote a binary operator that returns the integer quotient of two integers, i.e. (assuming that both integers are positive) $a \div b = \left\lfloor \frac ab \right\rfloor$.  This corresponds to the [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers) operator in many programming languages (e.g. the `//` operator in Python).

I observed that, when $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive integers, the values of $(a \div b) \div c$ and $a \div (b \times c)$ are equal.

I have tried to find a counter-example by using the following Python code, but wasn't able to find one:

```
from random import randint

while True:

    a = randint(1, 10000000000)
    b = randint(1, 10000)
    c = randint(1, 10000)

    lhs = a//b
    lhs = lhs//c

    rhs = a//(b *c)

    if lhs != rhs:
        print a, b, c
        break
```

Could anyone please provide a counter example if the assertion that I made is not true or a proof which shows that it is always true?

Additional Information:

1. Please note that all the division operators used above correspond to **integer division**.
2. The version of Python is 2.7.12.
3. I asked this question on StackOverflow and it was suggested there, that I ask it here.
4. I was not able to find a tag which says integer-division, so I didn't use it and any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Already proven in 1994. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Nested_divisions).

Comment: The difference between computing and mathematics is when b*c causes arithmetic overflow (e.g. 16b or 32b int). Then a/(b *c) should be 0 but instead it'll cause overflow.

Comment: I [answered this on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112911/is-it-safe-to-replace-a-bc-with-a-b-c-when-using-integer-division/45113310#45113310) a few months ago.

Comment: IMO, whoever told you to move this here was mistaken. While this question may indeed fall marginally within the [scope](/help/on-topic) of Math.SE (and could be made a better fit here with some editing to generalize it and make it less Python-specific), it would've been a much better fit for SO, or perhaps for [cs.SE]. SO's scope does seem to be gradually shifting towards "fix my code", with some folks there nowadays flat out claiming that any question without code to debug is off-topic (even though [officially](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it's not). IMO, this is unfortunate.

Comment: @smci: For Python that's not an issue, since it uses [arbitrary-precision integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) that don't overflow.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I'm very well aware of that, but the title merely says *" integer division"*, and the body says *"in many languages"* and doesn't restrict the scope to Python, it only mentions it. This is a very real issue in C/C++/R/Java/SQL/assembly/Fortran/etc.

Comment: @smci: Agreed. I just wanted to clarify that the difference you pointed out doesn't *always* exist (and, in particular, that it doesn't exist for the specific language the OP used, explaining why they didn't find a counterexample).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: agreed. "99% of computing", then. Also C#. And I suspect Mathematica, Javascript, Ruby, Scheme etc. Related: [LanguageDesign.SE: Why is Arithmetic Overflow ignored?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/348535/why-is-arithmetic-overflow-ignored). Yeah we should not rely on one language or compiler(/interpreter) for computer proofs.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360004/prove-that-lfloor-lfloor-x-a-rfloor-b-rfloor-lfloor-x-ab-rfloor

Comment: @smci that deserves to be an answer.

Comment: @RonJohn: I'm not sure because this is Mathematics.SE . Is the difference between maths and computer arithmetic on-topic here?

Comment: another duplicate on stackoverflow: [integer division properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2634546/995714)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Write $a=qb+r$, with $0 \le r \lt b$, so that $a \div b=q$.

Then write $q=sc+t$, with $0 \le t \lt c$, so that $(a \div b) \div c=s$.

We now have $a=b(sc+t)+r=bcs+bt+r$. As $$\begin{aligned} bt+r &\le b(c-1)+(b-1) \\ &=bc-b+b-1 \\ &=bc-1, \end{aligned}$$ we have $a \div (bc)=s$.

Comment: The initial bound on $bt + r$ took me a while to understand. Perhaps a statement clarifying the switch from $t < c$ to $t \le c-1$, and $r < b$ to $r \le b-1$, is in order? That seems like the central trick.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: this takes advantage of the discreteness of the integers.  If you are less than one you are less than or equal to the one below.  The neat thing is I get two $-1$s and I need both of them.

Comment: Yes, I know; I'm suggesting the detail be added to the answer.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: It seems my answer is a much easier way to do it, just by applying the division algorithm with $bc$ first instead of $b$ first. No need to play with ones. =)

Answer (score 4):

It's slightly easier to do the other way than Ross.

Let $q,r$ be integers such that $a = b·c·q+r$ and $0 \le r < b·c$. Then $r \div b \le r / b < c$.

Then $( a \div b ) \div c = ( c·q + ( r \div b ) ) \div c = q + ( r \div b ) \div c = q = a \div ( b·c )$.

(We simply twice used the easy fact that $(d·x+y) \div d = x + y \div d$ for integers $x,y,d$ with $d > 0$.)

Comment: This is a nice proof; can you mention that you're using $\div$ to mean integer division?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Oh, well it was defined in the question itself so I thought I didn't need to redefine it. =)

Comment: Oh I see... I read the question when it didn't have that notation, and didn't reread it afterwards :-) Now I see it, so feel free to ignore my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think about this is, say you have $N$ candies that you want to distribute among $a * b$ kids. What is the maximum number of candies a kid can get, given that you distribute the candies equally.

The answer is $\Big\lfloor\frac{N}{a*b}\Big\rfloor$

Note that you can divide the $a * b$ kids into $a$ classes. Since each student gets an equal number of candies, each class also gets an equal number of candies, which is $\le \left\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\right\rfloor$. Now for each class, you distribute these many candies among $b$ kids, so each kid gets

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\right\rfloor}{b}\right\rfloor$$

Hence,

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\right\rfloor}{b}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{N}{a*b}\right\rfloor$$

---

I didn't prove that we can give $\Big\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\Big\rfloor$ candies to each class and still ensure that each student will get the optimal number of candies. This can be proven easily as well. Let's say each class gets $Y$ candies in the optimal solution. Then, we have:

$$
Y * a \le N
\implies Y \le \frac{N}{a}
$$

Hence we can give each class $\left\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\right\rfloor$ candies for optimal distribution.

Note that each class can also reject some candies.

Answer (score 1):

$$a \text{\\} b  \text{\\} c = d$$
$$\exists x.~~ a\text{\\}b = x ~~\land~~ x\text{\\}c = d$$
$$\exists x.~~ xb \in [a - b + 1 \dots a]  ~~\land~~ cd \in  [x - c + 1 \dots x]$$
$$\exists x.~~ xb \in [a - b + 1 \dots a]  ~~\land~~ bcd \in  [xb - bc + b \dots xb]$$
$$\exists x.~~ xb \in [a - b + 1 \dots a]  ~~\land~~ bcd \in  [(a - b + 1) - bc + b \dots a]$$
$$bcd \in [a - bc + 1 \dots a]$$
$$a\text{\\}(bc) = d$$

Comment: I've deleted my previous comments because they no longer apply to the revised (completely rewritten) answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work always, because it is mathematical tautology $-$ not an obvious one though. Let's denote integer division by $\div$, and say we have $(a\div b)\div c=s$. This means

$$a\div b=sc+r_c\quad\implies\quad a=(sc+r_c)b+r_b=sbc+\underbrace{r_cb+r_b}_R$$

where $r_c\in\{0,...,c-1\}$ and $r_b\in\{0,...,b-1\}$ denote the remainder after division by $c$ and $b$ respectively. We therefore have

$$R=r_cb+r_b\le b(c-1)+b-1=bc-b+b-1=bc-1<bc.$$

This suffices to conclude that

$$a\div(bc)=(sbc+R)\div(bc)=s$$

since $R$ is to small to make a difference after the division.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\div$ denote integer division, and $/$ normal division. Let $a,b,c$ be integers and $x$ an abitrary number.

First observation: 
Because we're dividing an iteger, the division $(a+x)\div b$ can only be greater than $(a\div b)$ when x is at least 1, i.e. $x\ge 1$.

Furtrher we already know that $(a/b)/c = a/(b\cdot c)$ for regular division holds.

Therefore, the only reason integer division $\div$ wouldn't hold for $(a\div b)\div c$ would be when the first division cuts off so much, the second division has an altered result.

We can now split $a$ in a divisble part $p\cdot b$ and a remainder $q$. Note that the remainder is smaller than $b$.

However, because it's a remainder, $q/b$ is smaller than 1. And because it's smaller than one, and $a\div b$ is an integer, 
$(a\div b)\div c = p\div c= (p + q/b)\div c $

And therefore, the equality $(a\div b)\div c) = a\div (b\cdot c)$ holds.

Comment: (1) Unbalanced parentheses need fixing. (2) The right-hand side of the double-implication is not a statement.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it